# decrease size of markers used in basemap and get fullscreen

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to draw around 7000 points in a map of Germany. I am interested in the points in Germany, the other points are not so interesting. How can this be made better so that you can see more?

The best thing would be a fullscreen plot (plot horizontal instead of vertical), and the points need to be smaller. Also it would be nice if there were the substates of Germany. But I don't know how this works.

Here's an image of what it looks like right now.
[image]

This is the code. There are only some sample points in it, the real points are retrieved from a file. But this shows the basic code.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


plt.figure(1)
map = Basemap(projection='merc',
resolution='l',
llcrnrlat=44.0,
llcrnrlon=5.0,
urcrnrlat=57.0,
urcrnrlon=17)
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcountries()
map.fillcontinents(color='lightgray')
map.drawmapboundary()

long1 = np.array([ 13.404954,  11.581981,   9.993682,   8.682127,   6.960279,
6.773456,   9.182932,  12.373075,  13.737262,  11.07675 ,
7.465298,   7.011555,  12.099147,   9.73201 ,   7.628279,
8.801694,  10.52677 ,   8.466039,   8.239761,  10.89779 ,
8.403653,   8.532471,   7.098207,   7.216236,   9.987608,
7.626135,  11.627624,   6.852038,  10.686559,   8.047179,
8.247253,   6.083887,   7.588996,   9.953355,  10.122765])

lat1 = np.array([ 52.520007,  48.135125,  53.551085,  50.110922,  50.937531,
51.227741,  48.775846,  51.339695,  51.050409,  49.45203 ,
51.513587,  51.455643,  54.092441,  52.375892,  51.36591 ,
53.079296,  52.268874,  49.487459,  50.078218,  48.370545,
49.00689 ,  52.030228,  50.73743 ,  51.481845,  48.401082,
51.960665,  52.120533,  51.47512 ,  53.865467,  52.279911,
49.992862,  50.775346,  50.356943,  49.791304,  54.323293])

x, y = map(long1, lat1)
map.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are several questions and it would be better to split them up.

In the mean time, Evan Mosseri already answered the question about the markersize. An alternative would be to simply use the dot-marker, as I'll show. He also showed how to maximize the figure, I'll use an alternative whereby the size of the figure is just predefined.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))  # predefined figure size, change to your liking. 
# But doesn't matter if you save to any vector graphics format though (e.g. pdf)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.05,0.9,0.85])

# These coordinates form the bounding box of Germany
bot, top, left, right = 5.87, 15.04, 47.26, 55.06 # just to zoom in to only Germany
map = Basemap(projection='merc', resolution='l',
    llcrnrlat=left,
    llcrnrlon=bot,
    urcrnrlat=right,
    urcrnrlon=top)
map.readshapefile('./DEU_adm/DEU_adm1', 'adm_1', drawbounds=True)  # plots the state boundaries, read explanation below code
map.drawcoastlines()
map.fillcontinents(color='lightgray')

long1 = np.array([ 13.404954,  11.581981,   9.993682,   8.682127,   6.960279,
6.773456,   9.182932,  12.373075,  13.737262,  11.07675 ,
7.465298,   7.011555,  12.099147,   9.73201 ,   7.628279,
8.801694,  10.52677 ,   8.466039,   8.239761,  10.89779 ,
8.403653,   8.532471,   7.098207,   7.216236,   9.987608,
7.626135,  11.627624,   6.852038,  10.686559,   8.047179,
8.247253,   6.083887,   7.588996,   9.953355,  10.122765])

lat1 = np.array([ 52.520007,  48.135125,  53.551085,  50.110922,  50.937531,
51.227741,  48.775846,  51.339695,  51.050409,  49.45203 ,
51.513587,  51.455643,  54.092441,  52.375892,  51.36591 ,
53.079296,  52.268874,  49.487459,  50.078218,  48.370545,
49.00689 ,  52.030228,  50.73743 ,  51.481845,  48.401082,
51.960665,  52.120533,  51.47512 ,  53.865467,  52.279911,
49.992862,  50.775346,  50.356943,  49.791304,  54.323293])

x, y = map(long1, lat1)
map.plot(x,y,'.')  # Use the dot-marker or use a different marker, but specify the `markersize`.
```

The data that is at the basis for the states is obtained from a shapefile. These can be obtained from e.g. [Global Administrative Areas](http://www.gadm.org/) (the ones from this website can can be used for *non-commercial purposes only*)

That'll result in:

[image: basemap projection of Germany with states].

As for the final question: if you have coordinates in the arrays `lat` and `long` that are not within Germany, you'll have to filter them out. One way in which you could do this is to use the [geocoder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder/1.0.6) module, pass in the `(lat, lon)` and check if the returned result contains the dictionary key-value pair `"country": "Germany"`.

Comment: Very nice! How can i give the other countries next to Germany a different color?

Comment: Please ask it as a new question, it is more useful for people who use the search functionality.

Answer (score 2):

if I understand what you are trying to do correctly, it should be as simple as: `map.plot(x,y,'o',markersize=2)`
or whatever markersize you want

also add this before `plt.show():`

```
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.frame.Maximize(True)
```